# Use "facet_wrap" in ggplot2 with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-processing, ggplot2

I'm using QGIS 2.6.1 and R version 3.2.2.

I'm struggling to get the syntax on a R Script for creating plots via QGIS processing to work. My understanding is that R syntax in QGIS Processing is slightly different from other R interfaces ... and I specifically can't get `facet_wrap` of `ggplot()` to generate panels of histograms for my data.

In essence, I have a vector layer with polygon land cover features that I appended mean temperature values for each feature to. I used the "join attributes by location" function to calculate the average of all mean temperature tiles from the BioClim mean temperature raster dataset. A glimpse of the data is here:

[image: Screenshot of Attribut Table]

I now want to create a panel of histograms using `ggplot()` that shows the distribution of mean temperature ("MEANDN") for each of the difference Forest Types ("Forest Typ").

The code for generating a histogram across all forest types works:

```
##Vector Processing=group
##showplots
##Layer=vector
##X=Field Layer

library("ggplot2")

ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(Layer[[X]]/10))
```

However, if I add in a `facet_wrap()` call to try to generate distinct plots for each forest type to show:

```
# Example attempt... I added in a "##Y=Field Layer" call,
# just didn't show so here.
ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(Layer[[X]]/10)) +
facet_wrap(~Layer[[Y]], ncol=3, scales="free")
```

Does anyone have any clues on how the syntax should look to get `facet_wrap` to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ggplot2` always expects a data frame as input. See [ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis (Use R!)](http://www.ggplot2.org/book/), Section 4.4 Data:

> The restriction on the data is simple: it must be a data frame. This
>   is restrictive, and unlike other graphics packages in R. Lattice
>   functions can take an optional data frame or use vectors directly from
>   the global environment. Base methods often work with vectors, data
>   frames or other R objects. However, there are good reasons for this
>   restriction. Your data is very important, and it’s better to be
>   explicit about exactly what is done with it. It also allows a cleaner
>   separation of concerns so that ggplot2 deals only with plotting data,
>   not wrangling it into different forms, for which you might find the
>   plyr or reshape packages helpful. A single data frame is also easier
>   to save than a multitude of vectors, which means it’s easier to
>   reproduce your results or send your data to someone else.

or the upcoming version [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2-book/blob/master/book/tex/layers.tex#L122:L141).

The following should work:

```
##Vector Processing=group
##showplots
##Layer=vector
##X=Field Layer
##Y=Field Layer

library("ggplot2")

ggplot(data=data.frame(x=Layer[[X]]/10, y=Layer[[Y]])) +
   geom_histogram(aes(x=x)) +
   facet_wrap(~y, ncol=3, scales="free")
```

Comment: Thanks for this -- the added information is helpful. For some reason the script you suggested still isn't producing plots. Any other ideas as to why that might be?

Comment: Oops -- seems the errors on my end. The two variables are of different lengths and were throwing errors. Thanks again!